# How do I view robots.txt files in localhost?

Tags: localhost, aurelia, robots.txt

I have created a robots.txt file in an aurelia project and I want to check if it works correctly, how can I know if the file is working.

is there any way to see it from my localhost?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPT2f.png)

content of the robots.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

the file is created, I was hoping to visualize it.